# How to show $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(1,3)} 3x^2 y -xy^3 = -18$ with $\epsilon -\delta$?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

To prove : $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(1,3)} 3x^2 y -xy^3 = -18$ with $\epsilon -\delta$

We should show that for each $\epsilon >0, $ there exists $\delta$ s.t

$0<|\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + (y-3)^2}| <\delta $ implies $|3x^2y -xy^3 +18 |<\epsilon$

So I am trying to make a relationship between epsilon and delta from the two inequalities, but it is hard for me to find it.

How can I do it?

Comment: Try polar coordinates centered on $(1, 3)$

Comment: ...or introduce the displacements $h = x - 1$ and $k = y - 3$ and expand $3x^2y-xy^3+18$ in $(h, k)$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang could u be more specific please?

Comment: First substitute $x = 1 + h$ and $y = 3 + k$; then expand and see what you have. This should be a polynomial with constant term $0$. The goal is to show its absolute value can be made arbitrarily small ($<\varepsilon$) by assuring $|h|$ and $|k|$ are sufficiently small ($<\delta$). It will help to note that $\max(|h|,|k|)\leq\sqrt{h^2+k^2}=|(h,k)|$. <> When you write up the details, please post an answer; I'd be happy to upvote!